# showing c=a v b=c from a=c v b=c?

Tags: logic, proof

I am currently using the book Language, Proof and Logic

So far I have
**1**. a=c v b=c

subproof
**2**. a=c =intro
**3** c=c =elim 1,2
**4**. c=a =elim 2,3

end subproof

new subproof
**5**. b=c 
**6**. c=c =intro
**7.** c=b =elim 5,6

and when i end this subproof, and put down:
**8**. c=a v b=c velim 1, 2-4, 5-6

it is invalid? 
I am not sure how to approach this

Comment: Does the problem prohibit using symmetry of equality?

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly valid. Your derivation doesn't seem exactly right, but it can be modified to become correct.

[image]

Comment: Is this some kind of software package? Which is it? (Just curious.)

Comment: It's from the old edition of _Language, Proof, and Logic_. Barwise & Etchemendy have named it _Fitch_. (You have to admit, it looks much sexier than the new version that you can see in the modified question.)